# scp asks for passphrase even if the private key doesn't have one

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I am trying to automate a file copy task from one host to another. First of all, I create a private-public key pair from my own machine (without passphrase), and I upload the public key to let's say the receiver host B, at `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` using the password. After that, I test that I can access B through the ssh, and it works fine. Then, I copy my private key to host A which is the sender. I try to copy a file using scp `scp -i ~/.ssh/my_private_key test.png root@x.x.x.x:/root/test.png`, but it asks me for a passphrase, although I am sure I did not set any passphrase. I also tried using a key with a passphrase, and it did not accept it.

When I create a private-public key directly in A, it works. Does this has to do with moving the private key from one host to another? Any workaround for this? (In my case, I will using private keys from end-users, so they will definitely not be created locally).

Comment: Check the permissions of your key. They should be 600

Comment: As @RomeoNinov said - please check the permissions of the `.ssh` dir on both machines, too. If they are too permissive, e.g. private keys are accessible by group/others in the filesystem, the keys will **not** be used.

Comment: Thanks, it works now after changing the permissions

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't ever need to copy a private key.

Looking at the command you referenced:

```
scp -i ~/.ssh/my_private_key test.png root@x.x.x.x:/root/test.png
```

To work, you would need the public key corresponding to `my_private_key` to be in the `authorized_keys` file on the remote server.  Since you're sending to root, it should be in user root's `authorized_keys` file.

You may want to consider installing and using the [keychain](https://www.funtoo.org/Keychain) package, which is in the repository of many Linux distros.  When it's installed and you create a `~/.keychain` directory, you only get prompted for your passphrase(s) the first time you log in after bootup.  You can log out and in again and you won't be prompted because the decrypted key is stored in memory.

If you want cron jobs to copy file passwordlessly, they can source `~/.keychain${HOSTNAME}-sh`.

Alternately, you could use `ssh-agent`, but you'll need to reenter your passphrase every time you log in.

Comment: Thanks for info, this is good to know, but it did not help with the issue. It was a permissions issue.